# Typos in letter A and Typos in letter B (Rephrasing)

Tags: expressions

Sentence: *There are typos in letter A and there are typos in letter B.*

Note: The typos in letter A may be different from those in letter B.

Can I rephrase the sentence to "*There are typos in letter A and letter B.*"?

If so, does this rephrasing cause ambiguity (because people may think that the typos in letter A and the typos in letter B may be the same)?

Comment: It is unlikely people would expect the same typos unless the letters are identical

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with your construction. The letters both have typos, but it's neither expressed nor implied that they are the *same* typos.

(Personally, I would say *there are typos in both letters A and B*, but that's just a matter of choice. Whatever phrasing you use, I don't think anybody would be confused.)

Note that if you *wanted* to express similarity, you could phrase it as *both letters A and B have the same typos*.